# Notation for infinite cartesian products

Tags: soft-question, notation

This is a soft question, feel free to delete it if deemed inappropriate for the site. What is the best notation for the cartesian product of an infinite number of copies of the same set $E$? Maybe one can write $E^\mathbb{N}$ in the countable case, and $E^I$ for a larger set of indices, but are you aware of a more standard notation? I know one can write "$\prod_iE_i$ with $E_i=E$ for all $i$" but this is quite inefficient.

Related question: what about other types of products? e.g., the product $\sigma$-algebra of a sequence of copies of the same $\sigma$-algebra $\mathcal{A}$. I use $$\otimes_\mathbb{N}\mathcal{A}$$
since $\mathcal{A}^\mathbb{N}$ would be ambiguous, but probably you have better ideas.

Comment: $\mathcal{A}^{\otimes\mathbb{N}}$ seems quite standard.

Comment: Thank you, that seems perfect

Comment: Why wouldn't you write $\prod_iE$ instead of "$\prod_iE_i$ with $E_i=E$"?

Answer (score 2):

I would use $E^{\mathbb{N}}$ for the set of functions from $\mathbb{N}$ to $E$, that is the sequences of elements of $E$. If rather than sequences you consider elements of a free monoid (aka strings, words, etc...), I'd use $E^{\omega}$, particularly when endowed with the standard product topology taking every copy of $E$ as discrete.

For the cartesian product seen purely as a set, I'd use $E^{\times\mathbb{N}}$ or something similar.

Comment: I would tend to read $E^{\times\mathbb{N}}$ as $(E^\times)^\mathbb{N}$

Comment: Well...you know which kind of animal your $E$ is :) However, the improvement by Iosif Pinelis (which I saw after posting my answer) seems to take care of this.